# For what value(s) of $a,b$ does this limit hold?

Tags: limits, derivatives

> For which value(s) of $a$ and $b$ is $$ \lim_{x \to 0}(x^{-3}\sin(3x)+ax^{-2}+b)=0$$

**My Attempt**
Firstly I rewrote it into this form;
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{x^3}+\dfrac{a}{x^{2}}+b\right)=0$$
Then by putting them all under one common denominator,
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(3x)+xa+x^2b}{x^3}\right)=0$$
So the above is the identity we want to hold; 
If we just look at the limit;
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(3x)+xa+x^2b}{x^3}\right)$$ we can see L'Hopital can be used on this as for all  $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ this is a $0/0$ type limit; differentiating gives;
$$\left(\dfrac{3\cos(3x)+a+2xb}{3x^2}\right)$$
Now I am stuck on how to decide which value of $a,b$ hold; if $a=-3$ and for all values of $b$ at $x=0$ the above fraction would be of the form $0/0$ would I then differentiate again?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Notice $\sin(3x)=3x-9x^3/2+O(x^5)$

Comment: Yes, you have to take $a=-3$ to have a limit of the form $0/0$ (because in other case the original limit does not exist). Then you apply L'Hopital again.

Comment: Should have been $x^3b$, not $x^2b$. And use Taylor expansion, that's easier.

Comment: Yes, in order to continue assume $a=-3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then by putting them all under one common denominator,
>   $$ \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin(3x)+xa+x^2b}{x^3}\right)=0$$

You have made a mistake here; $x^2b$ should be $x^3b$.
For the next part, you correctly use L'Hopital, but with the $x^3b$ term it gives you the slightly different answer
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{3\cos(3x)+a+3x^2b}{3x^2}\right)
$$

> Now I am stuck on how to decide which value of $a,b$ hold; if $a=-3$ and for all values of $b$ at $x=0$ the above fraction would be of the form $0/0$ would I then differentiate again?

Yes, exactly.  Since the denominator approaches $0$, you need the numerator to also approach $0$ if the limit is to exist.  So $a = -3$, and then you differentiate again to get
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{-9\sin(3x) + 6xb}{6x}\right)
$$

Apply L'Hopital again...
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{-27\cos(3x) + 6b}{6}\right)
$$
You don't need to apply L'Hopital anymore, as the denominator is now nonzero.
But you need this limit to evaluate to $0$.  So what is $b$?

Answer (score 0):

For the above limit to exist, $a$ must be equal to $-3$.  Putting $a=-3$, you again have a $\frac{0}{0}$ form and hence you apply L'hopital to reach your answer.
Hope this was helpful. :)

Comment: This is a helpful answer but it's a bit unclear and not written too well.  Please consider improving the formatting and spending a bit more time on your answers.